# Cases of additive groups in which addition is "rightward elongation" and subtraction is "leftward elongation" of a left-to-right ordered string

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, formal-languages, turing-machines, computer-algebra-systems

Are there any known real-world instantiations of additive groups/rings in which addition is rightward elongation of a left-to-right ordered string and subtraction is leftward elongation of a left-to-right ordered string ?

In this regard, note that:

1) duplex DNA, i.e. the classical "double-helix" type of DNA, has two ANTIparallel strands, meaning that:

a. each of the two strands has a 5'-3' direction and a 3'-5' direction

b. the 5'-3' direction on one strand is the 3'-5' direction on the other, and vice-versa, of course.

2) any segment of classical duplex "double-helix" DNA can be elongated IN EITHER direction, i.e. if we pick a direction on one strand, say the 5'-3' direction, then it is true that the duplex itself can elongate in this direction, or in the opposite 5'-3' direction on the other strand

3) therefore, if we consider a duplex segment as a WHOLE (not one or the other of its strands), then the segment can elongate in either one of two directions.

Also, it is probably important here to note that there are species which exhibit closed "circular DNA duplexes", analagous to projective lines vs affine lines.

Comment: Shouldn't subtraction undo addition? How could this be if both act by elongating strings?

Comment: @Joppy - thanks very much for taking the time to respond.  The answer to your question is that here is a fundamental biomolecular operation or relationship called "reverse complementation" which can be used to guarantee that elongation in one direction is always by an element that is a well-defined inverse of an element used to elongate in the opposite direction.

Comment: I'd need to see a concrete example of the kind of operation you're talking about to really think about this.  It sounds vaguely operad-ic, but I doubt that would get you anywhere.

Comment: @Randall - thanks so much for taking the time to respond.  If you can provide  link to "things operad-ic", I'd be very grateful.  Regarding a concrete example, all you need to know that if you have a string S over the four DNA bases, say S = tccagg, then in order to "reverse complement" this string, you simply flip the string and translate a>t, c>g, g>c, t>a (yielding cctgga in this case.)  So, one can always choose to bi-directionally elongate using ONLY certain pairs of elements related to one another as true inverses.

Comment: The wikipedia page for operad theory contains references to all the standards.  Again, I'm not convinced this will be fruitful, but it might lead you down an informative rabbit hole.

Comment: @Randall - I ain't scared - I been down them before, too many times !!!! LOL !!!!!! Thank you so much again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invent such a structure. Consider the set $S$ of all strings containing zeroes followed by ones: $\mathtt 0^a\mathtt 1^b$. We can give this set the structure of an additive group by saying that $\mathtt 0^a\mathtt 1^b + \mathtt 0^m\mathtt 1^n = \mathtt 0^{a+m}\mathtt 1^{b+n}$. The identity is the empty string. Furthermore, let's declare that an equal number of ones and zeroes can cancel out, so that $\mathtt 0^a  \mathtt 0^c\mathtt 1^c \mathtt 1^b \equiv \mathtt 0^a  \mathtt 1^b$.

Now every string is equivalent to a list of ones (if it has more ones than zeros) or a list of zeros (if it has more zeroes than ones), or the empty string (if they're equal).  In other words, we've recreated the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ in unary. With this setup, you can add to a number by appending ones on the right, or subtract from it by appending zeros on the left.

The extension to DNA with leading and lagging strands is left as an exercise for the reader.